# Java ignoring input occasionally

Tags: java, loops, prompt

So I m new here and to programming in general I have been working on a rock paper scissors game where the user enters the letter and plays against the computer, however my input is sometimes ignored and the games restarts other times it plays on I have spent countless hours trying to figure out why this happens. Here is the code

Comment: It's happening because [`Random::nextInt(int bound)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) returns a value in the range of `[0, bound)`, not `[1, bound]`.  You have if conditions that check for an impossible value (`3`), but none for `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Method `.nextInt(n)` generates an Integer from and including `0` to and excluding `n` (in your case `0` to `2`). Basically it always "ignores" your input when the Computer generates a `0` since no `if` condition would be true. To fix your problem and generate a number from `1` to `n` use `.nextInt(n) + 1`.

Comment: Thanks for keeping simple perfectly explains things

Answer (score 1):

Add an else statement, and print the values of input and computer in it. You'll know the combinations you're not handling.

Something like..

```
}else if(input == 3 && computer == 3){
            report(computer,"tie with the computer");
else {
    System.out.println("input: " + input + "computer: " + computer); 
}
```